# apply custom shape to clip property CSS

Tags: css, customization, css-shapes, masking, clip

I'm just discovering and investigating the clip property of CSS. I've read that a rectangle or square object can be applied to the clip. After investigating and not finding a clear answer I decided to ask this question.

Is it posible to apply a customized object to the clip property?
Is it posible to manipulate with CSS this rectangle to a customized shape?

For example, could you apply a diagonal shape to the clip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is a bit of an old question but now you can use custom shapes with CSS clip-path.

You can find out more about it [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/).